# How do I find matches in various ranges in Excel for values in another range to be determined

Tags: excel, vba, range, matching

I have a macro that looks at the cells in a column for a table and compares it to the cells in another to determine the values of another column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Matches_Descriptions()
Dim compareRange As Range
Dim toCompare As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim I As Long

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Set compareRange = Worksheets("Car").Range("C4:C100000")
Set toCompare = Worksheets("Day").Range("E2:E100000")
Set rFound = Nothing

For Each cell In toCompare
    Set rFound = compareRange.Find(cell)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        cell.Offset(, -1).Value = rFound.Offset(, 1)
        Set rFound = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub
```

The macro searches for values in C4:C100000 and E2:E100000 that match and then the values for column B in the Car worksheet will be looked at and inputted into column D for the Day worksheet.

I found this macro from another question on this website and modified it slightly and it works. However, I am wondering if there is a possibility that I can compare more then two ranges to match. For instance this macro compares the C4:C100000 range in the car worksheet and compares the E2:E100000 range in the Day worksheet and finds a match. I want to make a macro that not only compares these two ranges but also compares Ranges B4:B100000 in the car worksheet and C2:C100000 in the Day worksheet. Can I essentially find two matches and these two matches will determine what values in the E column in the car worksheet will be inputted into the F column for the Day worksheet.

Ask for clarification if needed.

Here is a figure to show what I want to achieve

```
Car worksheet

Model        Colour code     Colour description

GT-R         XBG             red
Z-Coupe      CBG             yellow
GT-R         CBG             pink
Z-Coupe      XBG             blue
GT-R         XBG             red

Day worksheet
model    Colour code     Colour description

GT-R         XBG             Red
Z-Coupe      CBG             Yellow
GT-R         CBG             Pink
Z-Coupe      XBG             Blue
GT-R         XBG             Red
GT-R         TTC             ''No match
```

The colour description for the day worksheet is determined by the colour description of the car worksheet. 
Since these models and colour codes for the day worksheet have matches in the car worksheet,colour descriptions are displayed for the day worksheet. However there was no GT-R model and TTC colour code combination in the car worksheet so no colour description is displayed in the day worksheet for this combination.

Comment: You can repeat the code you have used above for the other ranges? How do the two matches determine the value in F?

Comment: For instance i'll give you an example in a situation. Let's say I have a colour code ABC for both worksheets. The description for this vehicle is Platinum blue however depending on the model of the car this description could change. For instance let's look at Nissan vehicles. The colour code "ABC" for a GT-R could be "platinium blue" but the colour code "ABC" for a Z-Coupe could be "Red steel". I need for this macro to match the colour codes and the models for both worksheets. When matched the appropriate colour description will be determined for the day worksheet.

Comment: I see. This should help http://www.xl-central.com/lookup-multiple-criteria.html It's a formula approach, but you could adapt to VBA if you really wanted. You could persist with a Find approach but every time you found the model you'd have to check the code before looking at the description.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me. I'm also going to have to use even more criteria then I showed in the question. A macro is much more intuitive to solve my problem, I have to match Nissan models, Nissan model years, Nissan colour codes, infiniti models. infiniti model years, and infiniti colour codes to find the appropriate colour description. I think for how specific the criteria is a macro may be better but maybe i'm wrong. Regardless thanks though for the advice

Comment: Maybe autofilter.